# Querying the users directory via the Java API

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I am trying to access/querying Domino directory using the Domino Java API and have a question regarding the same -

**Here is my setup -**

1. I am creating an application that uses Java Domino API to interface with the Domino Server
2. My Java application resides on its own server and uses the Java API (via DIIOP) to talk to the Domino server
3. The Domino server version in my environment is 9.0
4. There are multiple Domino servers in the environment and the user mailboxes are distributed across these Domino servers
5. My application receives an email address and message id from an external source as an input. Based on this input my application needs to delete the message from the user's mailbox.

**What am I stuck at -**
I want to query the Domino Directory server to identify the mail server name and the mail file name for the user (using the email address) so that my application can then open the user's mail file and then delete the corresponding message from the user's mailbox file.

As I was researching this I found the class/method [Directory.lookupNames()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_LOOKUPNAMES_METHOD_DIRECTORY_JAVA.html?lang=en) method which can be used to query the directory for users.

Will this method allow for searching users based on email address OR will it only search based on the user's name?

I tried test the above approach by invoking the [Session.getDirectory()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDIRECTORY_METHOD_JAVA.html) method but it throws a `NotesException - "Not implemented".` See below for my code snippet. The Session object is a valid (authenticated) Session object. What am I missing here?

Is there an alternate method/approach that I should be using to query the users from a Domino server?

Following is my code snippet -

```
private static boolean queryDirectory(Session dominoSession) {
    try {
        Directory dirDomino = dominoSession.getDirectory(null); 
        DirectoryNavigator dirNavigator = dirDomino.lookupNames("People", "John", "email");
        boolean bMatchFound = dirNavigator.findFirstMatch();
        while (true == bMatchFound) {
            String strValue = (String)dirNavigator.getFirstItemValue().get(0);
            System.out.println("Value - " + strValue);
            bMatchFound = dirNavigator.findNextMatch();             
        }
    }
    catch(NotesException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    catch(Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it means exactly what it says: the class was not implemented for IIOP by IBM. I'm putting this as a comment, not an answer, because I'm not 100% sure, but my recollection is that the Directory class was coded to take advantage of caching that is done inherently in the Domino back-end DLLs. When you're using IIOP you don't have a local copy of those DLLs. If the call went through to the server, it would hit the cache that's maintained in the server's DLLs with an unpredictable client load. The cache is very important for server performance, so IBM decided not to allow it.

Comment: Thanks Richard. Any guidance on how I should go about solving my problem - I have the user's email address. Is there something I could query via the Domino server so that I can get the mail server and the mail file associated with the email address ao that I can then programmatically attempt to delete the specific email from the user's mailbox?

Comment: I think I have found an alternative way to solve my problem -

Comment: I think I have found an alternative way to solve my problem -

The Domino Server is also a LDAP server and it is possible to query the Domino Server (programmatically) as a LDAP server and search using the email address and retrieve the mail server and mail file name for the user. E.g. the following command serves as an example to retrieve the Domino server and the mail file attributes for a user - 

`ldapsearch.exe -h <domino_server_ip> -D <domino_server_user> -w <domino_server_pass> "(mail=testuser@testdomain.com)" cn mail mailserver mailfile`

Comment: Yes. Not all Domino servers have LDAP enabled, but if your does that is a good way because Domino can be configured with multiple directory information sources and writing code to figure it all out can be quite difficullt, but Domino's LDAP service already knows how to do it.